# Why does finding files with regular expressions put the files in a different format than just listing them?

Tags: python, regex, shell, file-io

I'm writing a shell script that finds input files based on a regular expression. These input files are then passed as arguments to a python script. My code is as follows:

```
file_pattern=*test[0-9]*
files=$(ls -f $file_pattern)
python my_script.py $files
```

However, I found that $files doesn't pass the file names as a string separated by commas. My current workaround is manually listing all the desired input files as follows:

```
files=(test0.csv test1.csv test2.csv)
```

This passes "test0.csv, test1.csv, test2.csv" as a comma delimited string into python (which is what I want since I can just split the string into a list by the delimiter), but this can be tedious for many files. All the input files will follow the same naming convention so a regular expression is, in my opinion, the best option. Anyone know why/how I can solve this problem with the regular expression? Thank you!

Comment: That isn't a regular expression; it's a pattern. Where are you getting the idea that the array produces a comma-separated string?

Comment: sorry for the terminology mix-up. When I access the command line parameter in my python script using sys.argv[1], the result is a comma-separated string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array:

```
file_pattern=*test[0-9]*
files=( $file_pattern )
python my_script.py "${files[@]}"
```

or use the pattern directly

```
python my_script.py *test[0-9]*
```